# Regex to match sentence that contains keyword (should also work with abbreviations and numbers)

Tags: javascript, regex, search, sentence, abbreviation

I try to match the full sentence that contains a certain string (two nested capture groups).
It should also work if the sentence includes abbreviations such as `"e.g.|i.e.|R.S.V.P.|Mr.|Mrs.|approx.|…"`
or numbers with periods `10.000` but at the same time be defensive and not match short words followed by a period like `Test.` The method to identify the boundary of a sentence is basically finding a `.` character that is not part of an abbreviated or number.

**Open questions:**

a) **How can I reference and repeat the first capture group before the query?**

The allowed characters combinations repeat before and after the capture group (MYSEARCHQUERY). The performance suffers if the list of exceptions for abbreviations `(Mr.|Mrs|…)` is large – for English there are >400.

```js
export const englishAbbreviations = ['abbrev','absol','ad','aeronaut','af','agric','amer','anat','anthrop','anthropol','antiq','aphet','applic','appos','approx','arab','aram','assoc','astrol','astron','astronaut','attrib','austral','autobiogr','ave','bef','bibliogr','biochem','biol','bot','brit','bulg','bull','cal','canad','cat','catal','celt','cent','chem','chron','chronol','cinemat','cinematogr','clin','cogn','col','coll','collect','colloq','comb','comm','communic','comp','compan','compar','conc','conf','conj','cons','contrib','corr','corresp','crit','cytol','da','dat','deb','def','dem','dept','deriv','derog','devel','diagn','dial','dict','dim','dis','diss','du','ecol','econ','ed','edin','educ','ee','electron','elem','ellipt','embryol','engin','entomol','erron','ethnol','euphem','exam','exerc','exper','explor','fem','fig','finn','found','freq','fris','fund','gael','gaz','gen','geogr','geol','geom','geomorphol','ger','gloss','godef','goth','govt','gram','heb','hebr','her','herb','hind','hist','histol','hort','househ','housek','ibid','icel','ichthyol','id','ie','imit','immunol','impers','indef','inorg','introd','ir','irreg','it','jap','joc','jun','knowl','lang','lect','less','let','lett','lex','lit','lith','mag','magn','mal','man','managem','manuf','mar','masc','mataph','math','max','mdu','me','mech','med','mem','meteorol','mics','midl','mil','min','mineral','misc','mod','mus','mythol','narr','nat','naut','neurol','neut','no','nom','norw','nucl','numism','obstetr','occas','oe','of','ofris','oir','on','ophthalm','orig','ornith','os','outl','pa','palaeogr','palaeont','path','perh','pers','petrogr','petrol','pharm','philol','philos','phonet','photogr','physiol','pict','plur','poet','pol','polit','pop','porc','poss','pott','pple','pract','prec','pred','pref','prep','pres','princ','priv','prob','probl','proc','prof','pron','pronunc','prop','pros','prov','psychol','publ','quot','quots','radiol','rec','redupl','ref','refash','refl','reg','rel','reminisc','rep','repr','res','rev','rhet','rom','rum','russ','scand','sci','scot','scotl','sel','ser','sing','slav','soc','sociol','spec','stand','stanf','struct','stud','subj','subord','subseq','suff','superl','surg','taxon','technol','tel','telegr','teleph','theatr','theol','theoret','tokh','trans','trav','treas','treat','treatm','trig','trop','turk','typog','typogr','univ','usu','var','varr','vars','vertebr','vet','viz','voy','vulg','zoogeogr','zool'
];
```

b) **What’s a smarter way to identify a sentence that contains a search string? Any linguists here?**

Answer (score 0):

This regex pattern matches a string `(MYSEARCHQUERY)` (capture group2) and the sentence its embedded (capture group1).

```
/(
  (?:
    \b(?:[a-z]\.){2,}|
    \b(?:[a-z]*[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxysß]{3,}\.)|
    \b(?:[a-z][bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxysß]{2,}\.)|
    \b(?:[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxysß]+\.)|
    \b(?:\d*\.\d+)|
    \b(?:[a-z]\.)|
    [^\.\?\!]|
    (?:(?:mr|mrs|approx|prof)\.)
  )*

  (MYSEARCHQUERY)

  (?:
    \b(?:[a-z]\.){2,}|
    \b(?:[a-z]*[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxysß]{3,}\.)|
    \b(?:[a-z][bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxysß]{2,}\.)|
    \b(?:[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxysß]+\.)|
    \b(?:\d*\.\d+)|
    \b(?:[a-z]\.)|
    [^\.\?\!]|
    (?:(?:mr|mrs|approx|prof)\.)
  )*
)/gim
```

One Liner
`/((?:\b(?:[a-z]\.){2,}|\b(?:[a-z]*[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxysß]{3,}\.)|\b(?:[a-z][bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxysß]{2,}\.)|\b(?:[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxysß]+\.)|\b(?:\d*\.\d+)|\b(?:[a-z]\.)|[^\.\?\!]|(?:(?:mr|mrs|approx|prof)\.))*(MYSEARCHQUERY)(?:\b(?:[a-z]\.){2,}|\b(?:[a-z]*[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxysß]{3,}\.)|\b(?:[a-z][bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxysß]{2,}\.)|\b(?:[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxysß]+\.)|\b(?:\d*\.\d+)|\b(?:[a-z]\.)|[^\.\?\!]|(?:(?:mr|mrs|approx|prof)\.))*)/gim`

A **10x faster** one, but this one doesn’t catch single letter Abbreviations (A.) or exception like (Prof.|approx.)
`((?:\b(?:[a-z]\.){2,}|\b(?:[a-z]*[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxysß]{3,}\.)|\b(?:[a-z][bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxysß]{2,}\.)|\b(?:[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxysß]+\.)|\b(?:\d*\.\d+)|[^\.\?\!])*(MYSEARCHQUERY)(?:\b(?:[a-z]\.){2,}|\b(?:[a-z]*[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxysß]{3,}\.)|\b(?:[a-z][bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxysß]{2,}\.)|\b(?:[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxysß]+\.)|\b(?:\d*\.\d+)|[^\.\?\!])*)`

Link to try:
https://regex101.com/r/KWAaoF/2